# Proper way to directly pass yaml content to kubectl patch?

Tags: yaml, kubectl, patch

Example of functional `kubectl patch` command:

```bash
# kubectl patch storageclass local-path \
    -p '{"metadata": {"annotations": {"storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class": "false"}}}'
```

In certain cases the patched key/values are too numerous, so is recommended to use a file instead:

```bash
# kubectl patch storageclass local-path --patch-file=file.yaml
```

I would like to use an alternative of this format, which returns an error:

```bash
cat << 'EOF' | kubectl patch storageclass local-path --patch-file -
metadata:
  annotations:
    storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class: false
EOF
error: unable to read patch file: open -: no such file or directory
```

My goal is to use a dynamic way of pushing the patch data, without creating a file. What would be the correct format? Thank you.

Update: Based on provided documentation, I tried this format:

```bash
cat << 'EOF' | kubectl patch storageclass local-path --type=merge -p -
{
    "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
            "storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class": "false"
        }
    }
}
EOF
Error from server (BadRequest): json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type map[string]interface {}
```

Or:

```bash
kubectl patch storageclass local-path --type=merge -p << 'EOF'
{
    "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
            "storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class": "false"
        }
    }
}
EOF
error: flag needs an argument: 'p' in -p
```

What would be the correct format? I'm trying to avoid a very long line and keep a nice readable format.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation of [**kubectl patch help**](https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_patch/) applying a patch that way is not supported. You either need to pass the patch as a json string or from the file that contains the patch.

You can pass something like this, but still you need to clean up the file you created here (auto.yaml).

```
$ cat <<EOF | echo "metadata:
>  labels:
>   app: testapp "> auto.yaml | kubectl patch pod pod-name --patch-file=auto.yaml
> EOF
```

For more information about EOF refer to the **Here Document** section in this [document](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-io-redirections.htm)

**For Updated question:**

You are actually missing the `'` quotation before starting the json and don't give `-` after `-p`. Give a try like this, this is working in our environment

```
$ cat <<EOF | kubectl patch deployments nginx --type=merge --patch '{
> "metadata":
>   {
>     "labels":
>       {
>         "check": "good"
>       }
>   }
> }'
> EOF
```

Comment: I updated the question, based on your suggestion.

Comment: Hi @Floren did you get a chance to look into the answer? is it useful?